# Problem when using python xoltar toolkit, error raised when employ closure

Tags: python, functional-programming, closures

Recently I've been reading some materials about functional programming in Python, one of them is here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-prog2/index.html

I type the code:

```
from functional import *

taxdue        = lambda: (income-deduct)*rate
incomeClosure = lambda income,taxdue: closure(taxdue)
deductClosure = lambda deduct,taxdue: closure(taxdue)
rateClosure   = lambda rate,taxdue: closure(taxdue)

taxFP = taxdue
taxFP = incomeClosure(50000,taxFP)
taxFP = rateClosure(0.30,taxFP)
taxFP = deductClosure(10000,taxFP)

print"Functional taxes due =",taxFP()

print"Lisp-style taxes due =", \
      incomeClosure(50000,
          rateClosure(0.30,
              deductClosure(10000, taxdue)))()
```

but end up with following error information:

```
Functional taxes due =
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Study/python/FP/FP1.py", line 16, in <module>
    print"Functional taxes due =",taxFP()
  File "E:/Study/python/FP/FP1.py", line 5, in <lambda>
    taxdue =        lambda: (income-deduct)*rate
NameError: global name 'income' is not defined
```

I'm using python 2.7.1, I want to know what the problem is, thank you in advance.

Comment: there still some errors remain after adding parameters to lambda taxdue, asking for parameters when invoking taxdue directly or indirectly, it seem that the closure didn't bind the data to the parameter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variables `income`, `deduct` and `rate` aren't defined anywhere when you do `lambda: (income-deduct)*rate`.

Maybe you intended to make them parameters to the lambda?

Comment: yeah, but there still errors remain, asking for parameters when invoking taxdue directly or indirectly, it seem that the closure didn't bind the data to the parameter